# No code coverage with nosetests, despite option

Tags: python, code-coverage, nose

I want to generate a Cobertura style XML for code coverage of my python package. My command looks like this:

```
nosetests --verbosity=3 --cover-package=jenkinsqa --nocapture --nologcapture --with-xunit --cover-inclusive --cover-erase --with-xcoverage
```

Despite the presence of the `--with-xcoverage` option, no coverage.xml file is created. I tried to add a `--with-xcoverage-file=cov.xml` and still no output. The xunit results are saved correctly in `nosetests.xml`, and also a `.coverage` file. I know I could run after `coverage xml` to obtain the xml file from the `.coverage` file but I'd like to know why nosetests isn't doing the export. I'm using nosetests version 1.3.7 with nosexcover 1.0.11.

Answer (score 2):

To get the coverage information in xml format you need to add the `--cover-xml` argument

Comment: Can you try a command-line like this:
nosetests test_blah.py --with-xunit --with-coverage --cover-xml

Comment: nosetests test_check_input.py --with-xunit --with-coverage --cover-xml yields to a nosetests.xml but no coverage xml

Comment: I just ran this command on Ubuntu and Windows 10 and both generated .coverage, nosetests.xml and coverage.xml output files. I am using nose==1.3.7
nosexcover==1.0.11, as specified in the your question. Please try with a minimal test file. `from math import factorial

def test_fac_6():
    assert factorial(6) == 20`

Comment: It's working with the minimal exemple, don't know what's wrong in my test suite, I'll investigate more

Comment: I found it, I called a os.chdir in a test and it caused the coverage to be send elsewhere. Thx for your help stx101